# mobile slide in sidebar not working as planned

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

**what** would be the right combination of css and javascript for having a slidein sidebar

*I use jquery mobile, but just for convenience now*

I have content with 100% width and 1em margins on the side

**How can I make the sidebar slidein from the right and push the content to the left at the same time.**

I try'd it with containers for the sidebar and one for the content and setting the css to float left and position relative, but that obviously did not work, because then both are in view and I loose the 100% width.

I used this to quickly get it animated

```
var iSidebar = 0;

    function toggleSidebar(){


    if (iSidebar === 0) {
        iSidebar = 1;
        $(".sidebar").animate({
            left: -100
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
    else {
        iSidebar = 0;
        $(".sidebar").animate({
            left: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Can you create a working example of what you have so far on jsbin.com,  including html, css, and js.

Comment: try'd that for the first time anyway it's here i believe http://jsbin.com/iyuqet/1/

Comment: thanks.  so i see a green square that slides to the left when i click "click me".  what is supposed to be happening?

Comment: the green sidebar needs to slide in from the right and push the content to the left, I can make it do so if I make the containers not float and the sidebar position absolute and animate them both, but it's nowhere near perfect yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try animating the element you want pushed as well

```
if (iSidebar === 0) {
    iSidebar = 1;
    $(".sidebar").animate({
        left: -100
    }, {
        duration: 500
    });
    $(".someContent").animate({
        left: -100
    }, {
        duration: 500
    });
}
```

Comment: I am going further trying to make it work with css3, but thanks for the help